# Find two br toguether

Tags: php, regex

I want to find `<br /><br />` (just when there are 2 br toguether) and replace for something. But it does not seem to find it.

This is where to find, $text:

```
<p>first<br />
segon<br />
<br />
third</p>
```

I try a lot of things like: find br br, replace it for "something" that it is in $text. The problem is in the find

```
$p = str_replace("<br/><br/>", "something", $text);
```

I tried to find without success thinks like:

```
<br/><br/>, <br><br>, <br/>\n<br/>\n, <br/>\r\n</br>\r\n ...
```

Can anyone explain me why I cannot find `<br><br>`, please?

Comment: So `</br>` or `<br />`?

Comment: @_mulder I updated, thank you

Comment: Regexes are whitespace-sensitive, so `<br/>` can't match `<br />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace:

```
$html = '<p>first<br />
segon<br />
<br />
third</p>';
echo preg_replace("#<br />\s*<br />#", "something", $html);
```

or

```
echo preg_replace("#<(/)?br(\s*/\s*)?>\s*<(/)?br(\s*/\s*)?>#", "something", $html);
```

Second one matches matches all possibilities.

Output:

```
<p>first<br />
segonsomething
third</p>
```

Comment: There are several ways to specify `<br>` (in plain text). Your solution only addresses 1 way. I think it is better in this case to tokenize the HTML and search through it.

Comment: FYI, `<br>`, `</br  >`, `<br    >`, `<br  />` are all parsed as `br` tag. Only `< br>` is parsed as plain text.